# Jenkins's Docker Swarm plugin not resolving environment variables

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins, cloudbees, swarm

I am currently setting up a Cloudbees Jenkins cluster with the help of the docker swarm plugin. I got it to work once, but haven't gotten it to work ever since. I get several different errors related to the creation of the agent that executes the pipeline, but they all seem to be related to the environment variables that the plugin creates at runtime. Does someone know a solution to this?

```
[1:40:45 PM] Creating Service with Name : agt-vice_testing_59-72
[1:40:45 PM] ServiceSpec created with ID : kk0jxbuqvh4zyngruamxphl4b
[1:40:45 PM] ServiceSpec request JSON : {"TaskTemplate":{"ContainerSpec":{"Image":"docker:17.12","Command":["sh","-cx","docker run --rm --privileged java:8 sh -xc 'curl --connect-timeout 20 --max-time 60 -o agent.jar http://199.18.14.456:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar && java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JNLP_URL' "],"Env":["DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_SECRET=5ee89222c397f86c7ca8ecc6af73268539fa3ea9f64e46f815c4cfc06322aa0f","DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JAR_URL=http://199.18.14.456:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar","DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JNLP_URL=http://199.18.14.456:8080/computer/agt-vice_testing_59-72/slave-agent.jnlp","DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_NAME=agt-vice_testing_59-72"],"Dir":"/tmp","User":"root","DNSConfig":{"Nameservers":[],"Search":[],"Options":[]},"Mounts":[{"Target":"/var/run/docker.sock","Source":"/var/run/docker.sock","Type":"bind","VolumeOptions":null}],"Hosts":[],"Secrets":[],"Configs":[]},"RestartPolicy":{"Condition":"none","MaxAttempts":0},"Resources":{"Limits":{"NanoCPUs":0,"MemoryBytes":0},"Reservations":{"NanoCPUs":0,"MemoryBytes":0}},"Placement":{"Constraints":[]}},"EndpointSpec":{"Ports":[]},"Name":"agt-vice_testing_59-72","Labels":{"ROLE":"jenkins-agent"},"Networks":[]}
�+ docker run --rm --privileged java:8 sh -xc curl --connect-timeout 20 --max-time 60 -o agent.jar http://199.18.14.456:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar && java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JNLP_URL
d+ curl --connect-timeout 20 --max-time 60 -o agent.jar http://199.18.14.456:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
P  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
N                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
�
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  770k  100  770k    0     0  63.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 68.4M
+ java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl
#Option "-jnlpUrl" takes an operand
!java -jar agent.jar [options...]
```